# PowerShell foreach within function

Tags: function, powershell, variables, foreach, copy-item

I'm writing a function to collect logs for analysis.

I'm trying to use variables to keep it as tight as possible, but for some reason  the function won't create, moans about brackets and variables.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

```
FUNCTION GetLogs ($CompName)
{
$LOGS    = "CcmExec.log,Scheduler.log,WUAHandler.log"
$CCMPath = "C$\Windows\CCM\Logs"
$Target  = "C:\Temp\Logs"

foreach (file$ IN $LOGS ) {file$ = Copy-Item \\$CompName\$CCMPath\$LOGS $Target\$CompName-$LOGS}    
}
```

Comment: $file instead of file$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code won't work.

I think you meant to define an array in $LOGS, but you are actually defining just one String.

Try this: `$LOGS = "CcmExec.log", "Scheduler.log", "WUAHandler.log"`

Also it looks like you are trying to copy those 3 Files somewhere, but what you are doing is setting the var $file each turn to something else. The statement `$file In $LOGS` means that the variable $file will be  "CcmExec.log" the first time of the loop, then "Scheduler.log" and so on.

So what I think you want to do is this:

```
Function GetLogs ($CompName) {

$LOGS    = "CcmExec.log","Scheduler.log","WUAHandler.log"
$CCMPath = "C$\Windows\CCM\Logs"
$Target  = "C:\Temp\Logs"

foreach ($file In $LOGS ) {
       Copy-Item -Path \\$CompName\$CCMPath\$file -Destination $Target\$CompName-$file
    }    
}
```

I also removed some typos.

Is that about right?

Comment: Yes, I sort of knew about arrays, but not nearly enough to know what I didn't know!

Comment: Np. Accept my answer, it's more beautiful than Martin Brandl's ;)
Just kidding, both work, choose the one you like.

Comment: I've no standing and can't push these lovely answers up! It's a great answer and with reading Powershell in a month of lunches I will get my head around these concepts.

Answer (score 1):

You `$Logs` is just a string, not a string *array* thus you can't iterate over it. You can fix that using:

```
$LOGS    = "CcmExec.log", "Scheduler.log","WUAHandler.log"
```

Also you are assigning the result of the `CopyItem` to an invalid variable and don't use the current loop variable. Your function probably should look like this:

```
function Get-Logs
{
    Param
    (
        [string]$CompName
    )

    $logs    = "CcmExec.log", "Scheduler.log","WUAHandler.log"
    $ccmPath = "C$\Windows\CCM\Logs"
    $target  = "C:\Temp\Logs"

    $logs | ForEach-Object {
        Copy-Item -Path  "\\$CompName\$ccmPath\$_" -Destination "$target\$CompName-$_"
    } 
}
```

**Note:** You should probably rename your function to `Copy-LogsToLocal` or something...

Comment: Thank you Martin, I knew I was doing something wrong and your explanation and corrected code work wonderfully.

Comment: You are welcome. Please consider accepting the answer.